# How can I select part of the sentence in playwright?

Tags: javascript, playwright, playwright-test

In my automation script I have a sentence - "when will my account be ready?". From this sentence I want to select the word "account". So basically I want to highlight that text and then right click on it. I am stuck at highlighting the text "account" using automation tool playwright.

Page element looks like this.

```
<div class="line-text">when will may account be ready</div>
```

Comment: Is the word `account` linked to anything? Why do you want to select and right click? Is there a specific test case that you want to test?

Comment: No account word is not linked to anything. I want to right click on it to mask it.

Comment: If this sentence is just one text node and you did not select any text, right click would not know anything about the word under cursor. This information is not available to the web, you would not know which work that is. What do you mean "mask it"?

Comment: We have masking (hide important words) functionality in our application

Answer (score 1):

After trying many things, below code worked for me. Basically the word I was trying to select, didn't have any tag around it so was hard to select that word. I used JavaScript first to select the text and then right clicked using playwright.

```
// element handle of a complete sentence
const elementHandle = await this.getMessageByText(messageText);

// below code selects the given word from the line. text is the word I want to //select
    await elementHandle.evaluate((element, text) => {
      const selection = window.getSelection();
      const content = element.innerText;
      const range = document.createRange();
      range.setStart(element.childNodes[0], content.indexOf(text));
      range.setEnd(element.childNodes[0], content.indexOf(text) + text.length);
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);
    }, textToMask);

await this.click(SELECTORS.messageBodyTextelementHandle, { button: 'right' });
```